# When getItemCount and getItemViewType method get called in Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I saw similar questions in stackoverflow but they doesn't give clear answers to my question. Don't mark it as duplicate before reading my full questions. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748131/when-does-getitemcount-method-get-called-in-recycleview-adapter) link , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter) , and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937281/why-does-bindviewholder-accept-a-position-as-an-argument) too.
Thanks for spending your time to read this.

I gave my three questions below the Source code, kindly have a look at it.

I'll make it simple. I am trying to use **two** **ViewHolder** in Recycler Adapter which i am going to use in **ViewPager** for TabLayout. Both View Holder having **different** **Xml** and different elements (ie textview , imageview etc..) But got struck with several confusions inside it.

I implemented my RecyclerView adapter class as follows

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> { 


    public class MainViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       public MainViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
       }


    class ViewHolder0 extends MainViewHolder { 
        ... 
    } 

    class ViewHolder2 extends MainViewHolder { 
        ... 
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        /**** I don't know where and when this method will be called and what will be the value present in the variable "position" ****/
    } 

    @Override 
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...); 
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...); 
             ... 
         } 
    } 
      public int getItemCount() {
             /**** I don't know where and when this method will be called and   what will be the value present in the variable "position" ****/ 
     }
}
```

And my Questions are,

Q1. When and where getViewType is called and what will be in "**position**" variable and what do we need to return

Q2. When and where getItemCount is called and how can i return **correctly** (because i am using **two view holders and each will have different count** )

Q3. I created seperate Recyclerview Adapter class but it gave an error that RecyclerViewAdapter class **clashes** with the another one. (Since i am using them in same activity for TabLayout, i thought that error was thrown, am I correct? or is there any way to create seperate Adapter class)

If you can explain the full process of RecyclerViewAdapter, that would be awesome :) But please clarify my above confusions.

Any type of help welcomed, Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: `getItemCount` returns the total number of items in your `RecyclerView` and  `getViewType` is called with values [0..`cnt`-1] where `cnt` is returned by `getItemCount`

Comment: @pskink When i use two or more Holders in the same Adapter, Each holder will have its seperate Count and Seperate operations in OnCreate and OnBind, How can i identify and code it?

Comment: add some `Log.d` inside those methods, it is the best method of learning

Comment: @pskink Cool.. that's the preety awesome method. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q1)**
The getViewType() method will be called before the onCreateViewHolder() method each time your custom view is created.

You need to create a list with your custom list items `List<CustomItem> list=method_to_return_your_list()` and each of them with a getViewType() getter method.

In your get getItemViewType()

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return list.get(position).getViewType();
   /*this returns the view type of each element in the list*/
}
```

This can be either 0 or 1 considering your switch case statement in the **onCreateViewHolder()** method

**Q2)**
  The getItemCount() method should return the number of list items.

```
public int getItemCount() {
         return list.size();
 }
```

**Q3)**
Do not create another recyclerview adapter for the same recyclerview

**Also I fogot.**
   Instead of creating new ViewHolders ,just change the itemView in the view holder like

```
@Override 
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder(itemView0); 
         case 2: return new ViewHolder(itemView1); 
         ... 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you explain more about getItemViewType() , 1. Who and where this getItemViewType will be called with integer argument . i mean what will be in "position". Is it called each time for each ViewHolders or it will be called for OnBind method? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: This can be a getter method inside your CustomItem class which is the type of data list List<CustomItem> list; It has to be set when creating your list element like CustomItem item=new CustomItem();item.setViewType=0;list.add(item);